# TinyMCE & .Net - Error when POSTing with a single quote in the text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I am using the jQuery TinyMCE control in my .Net Web Forms application.
I primarily use it with AJAX and webservices however in one instance I have to let it post to the server as a part of the form.

For almost all input it works fine with

```
$('#<%= eText.ClientID %>').tinymce({
    encoding: 'xml'
});
```

However the moment I try to save a single quote `'` I get the unsafe input error.

What can I do to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oi, just when you give up and ask a SO question you find the answer on google.
I'm probably going to need this later so I'm going to leave this here.

Thanks to OP on this blog.
http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/22/96.aspx#414

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // ...
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onSaveContent.add(function (ed, o) {
            o.content = o.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For those using version 4:

```
setup: function (editor) {
   editor.on('SaveContent', function (ed) {
      ed.content = ed.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Confirmed that this works on version 4.

Comment: This solution surely works, but be really careful if you process tinyMCE output on server side and especially if saving to database (which is very common situation). *Always check if you escape single quotes on the server side*. The fact you cannot post single quotes via tinyMCE doesn't mean somebody can't hack you via e.g. [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)!

Comment: Thank you very much! Just wondering why this is not in the oficial documentation. This is a pre-req to work on asp.net and is not even mentioned.